# "Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor."

Tags: c#, json, configuration

I am trying to implement the options-pattern and get the following error:

> "Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor."

My setup is as this:

I have a Controller class like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

  private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
  private readonly MyConfig _myConfig;

  public MyController(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<MyConfig> myConfig){
    _httpClient = httpClient;
    _myConfig = myConfig.Value;  <<<<<<<<<<<< FAILS HERE
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get(){
  ....
  var myHttpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _myConfig.MY_ENDPOINT);
  ...
  ...
  }
}
```

I have a JSON file - my appsettings that goes something like this:

```
{
"Tracer": {
"Trace": {
  "Default": "",
  "Smari": ""
  }
},

"MY_DB": "",
"MY_USER": "",
"MY_PW": "",
"MY_ENDPOINT": "https://my-test-site/offering",
"MY_CIGO": ""
}
```

And in my Startup.cs I've written the following:

```
services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration);
```

Lastly my MyConfig class that goes like this:

```
public class MyConfig 
{
    public string MY_ENDPOINT { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone see, why it fails? I've checked my JSON file for syntax and it seems correct, so I am a bit lost.

Comment: looks like your `JSON` is not valid,  there are extra comma at the last item of any list for example `"Smari": ""`, should `"Smari": ""` and  `"MY_ENDPOINT": "https://my-test-site/offering",` should be `"MY_ENDPOINT": "https://my-test-site/offering"`

Comment: @styx - sorry thats my bad (bad copy into SO). Fixed the JSON, but the error is still the same though. Put the "new" JSON inside a validator and it passes so I dont think the error is in the JSON syntax...

Comment: What is `myConfig.Value`?

Comment: It has no value, but just states: myConfig.Value threw and exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException".

Comment: Did you post your whole appsettings.json file? I just tried it with your given json data without any issues.

Comment: Yes. Hmm.. That's odd... I do have a appsettings.json, appsetings.test.json, appsettings.prod.json and so on... They are not exactly the same, but all have a MY_ENDPOINT key in them?

Comment: My guess is that you have some kind of invalid json which can't be correctly deserialized by .Net

Comment: Check which appsettings.json file is taken for your current environment settings and check the file taken carefully for anything fishy in terms of the json format. Even if multiple json validators validated it successfully.

Comment: maybe a dumb question, but how do I check which of the appsettings.json files that is taken? I suspect that this might be the issue, since you don't have any problems running it with the json-text I've provided in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208626/discussion-between-croxy-and-badaboomskey).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on the chat discussion:

The issue was that the controller got instantiated inside of a test project by a helper class. This helper class expected an appsettings file with a given name (`appsettings.test.json`). But the test project didn't contain an appsettings file with the expected name. So adding an appsettings file with the correct name solved this issue.

Means for everyone else getting this error:
This error most likely occurs if something is wrong with the `appsettings.json` file. Either being it a format issue or the file not being existent at all. So check for the right filename and format (even if json validators validate it successfully).